# Firestore rules - match E.164 phone pattern

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, re2

I'm trying to enforce the users to pass an E.164 phone number. But for some reason, I get a syntax error in firestore about my regex:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to double escape everything `^\\+?[1-9]\\d{1,14}$`